# Subset array to members of another array in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am looking for a functionality i `Matlab` to subset and array like the `IN` function in SQL or `%in%` in R. I.e. I have the following data:

```
a = 1:3;
b = 2:4;
```

Then I want to write something like:

```
(a %in% b)
```

And it should produce:

```
ans =

     0     1     1
```

However using %in% clearly doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably looking for the function `ismember`, which checks which members of one matrix are also member of a second matrix. It returns true/false for each entry in your matrix `a` if it can/cannot be found in your matrix `b`.

```
ismember(a, b)
ans =

0     1     1
```

As a side note: `%` is the character, which starts a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it with [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
result = sum(bsxfun(@eq, a(:).', b(:)), 1);
```

This has the advantage that it tells you *how many* elements of `b` equal each element of `a`. For example,

```
>> a = [1 2 3];
>> b = [2 3 4 2];
>> result = sum(bsxfun(@eq, a(:).', b(:)),1)
result =
     0     2     1
```